# Retrieve stock balance by category from the following table

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have the following table structure

```
id  stock   category    created                 type    
11  10      4           2015-06-05 13:30:56     a
12  5       4           2015-06-05 13:31:30     s
14  12      6           2015-06-05 15:58:41     a
15  10      6           2015-06-05 15:59:07     s   
16  10      4           2015-06-05 16:00:18     a   
17  10      4           2015-06-05 16:00:52     a   
18  1       6           2015-06-05 16:01:23     a   
20  10      6           2015-06-05 16:51:48     a   
21  10      6           2015-06-05 17:00:23     s
22  10      4           2015-06-05 17:02:39     s   
23  45      7           2015-06-05 20:48:31     a
```

> Type 'a' is for stock added
>   Type 's' is for sale

I'm performing following query to get the stock balance, but I need to fetch the balance for each category.

Here is the query I tried so far:

```
SELECT (
    select SUM(stock)
    from stock
    where type='a'
) - (
    select SUM(stock)
    from stock
    where type='s'
) as balance
```

Comment: Do you have any errors? What do you got so far?

Comment: m getting total balance, but i need to fetch bal by category

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can try that (not tested)

```
select category
, sum(if(type='a', stock, 0)) - sum(if(type='s', stock, 0)) as balance
from stock
group by category
```

#### Edit:

I just tested it and it works

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PHP you can use this

```
SELECT SUM(stock) FROM stock WHERE type= 'a' AND category = 4
```

put the result in the $var1

```
SELECT SUM(stock) FROM stock WHERE type= 'b' AND category = 4
```

put the result in the $var2 and then do

```
$var = $var1 - $var2
```

you can loop the SQL calls and set the category number that you need.

There are more solution but I since I do not know the code that you use before and were you put this results this is the best that I can do.

Comment: That will work for only one category at the time. I don't think that's what OP wants

Comment: He needs to loop this SQL calls for all the categories if you limit it by category you will only get 1 result so you need to call SQL more times

Comment: But that's a bad habit to loop when it is not needed. I think in that case, it is not needed.